# What to do if your husband is muktzeh

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My husband is muktzeh (he was [born in the eighth month](/a/26856) and is now [nineteen](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/yevamos/insites/ye-dt-080.htm)). Our marriage is going well. However, sometimes on the three-day Yom Tov it becomes difficult that neither I nor anyone else can p̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶h̶i̶m̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶s̶  pass him to things at the table. Is there any solution for this?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: 3 days of no passing seems not too bad compared to Niddah...

Comment: @DoubleAA Right but it's not only me! No one can pass anything to him! He sits alone.

Comment: ask him to pass to you

Comment: I think this is misrepresenting the Halacha. Because he's muktzeh you can't move him, but you still may pass him items without physically moving his hand. In PTIJ, everything but the subject of the joke should be accurate. Perhaps it's your three year old who's muktzeh and likes to tantrum ; )

Comment: @LN6595 Aren't we not supposed to touch muktzeh? anyway Shabbos is a good time to be machmir

Comment: @SAH You can touch muktza if you don't move it (eg. a very big heavy item)

Answer (score 8):

From RaMBa"M's [*Hilchot Milah* - Chapter 1](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/932325/jewish/Milah-Chapter-One.htm)

Halacha 13

> Nevertheless, if such an infant remains alive for thirty days, he is considered to be a child who will live and is governed by all the same rules as other infants.

From this, I gather that since your husband is *muktzeh*, he must be younger than 30 days old (your question says he's 19, so I'm assuming you mean 19 days old).  Since you are implying that you are not *muktzeh* you must be older than 30 days old, but I will assume that you are also somewhere close to this age range so that things aren't *as* creepy.

As it turns out, since your husband is so young, you can't really be married after all. While the *kiddushin* can happen at a very young age, the minimum age for a marriage to take effect is 13 for boys and 12 for girls.  So simply don't worry about it.  Go play with your mommy and daddy for a few more years and then you can safely marry your husband when he turns 13 without any concern for him being *muktzeh*.

Comment: Rashi: "It is necessary to wait twenty years in order to determine that the person is fit to live and that he is not a Nefel, a stillborn."

Comment: (Trust me, if there were any doubt about it, my husband would be circumcised by now.)

Comment: a girl can be mikudeshes under 12 years old

Comment: @hazoriz Yes, note what I said in the answer. You can do kiddushin at a very young age, but she is not considered married until the age of 12. At that time, she has the option of selecting _mi'un_ and the marriage is retroactively annulled.

Comment: If someone that is not her husband has relations with her (I guess after she is 3) does he not get killed? (But if she was not married then he does not)

Comment: her husband is permitted to have relations with her before she is 12? (Do we not learn that when she has relations at age 11 she can use contraption)

Comment: What you are saying is only by a second marriage but if her father married her off the first time then she needs a get see http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10888-mi-un

Answer (score 4):

As someone who was born on the 9th day of the eighth month of the seventh year (of this century) of the sixth millenium (9 Cheshvan, 5707) I can understand your problem. Even if your husband is muktzah you do not have a problem.

First, being muktzah just means that you would not be allowed to move him from one place to another. Thus, you would not be allowed to pick him up and pass him to someone else. You would be allowed to pass to him other items at the table or to put something down next to him so that he can pick it up.

Second, since the two of you are married, he is a Kli shemelachto l'heter. Thus it is mutar to move him letzoraech gufo or letzorech mekomo. You would also be allowed to move him letzorech mitzvah. Thus oneg shabbos or oneg yom tov would also be allowed. This allows any of the things that are part of the oneg including those actions that require you to move or touch him.

Comment: is not a Kli shemelachto l'heter permitted to be moved for any tzoraech?

Comment: @hazoriz What other tzorech is there?

Comment: (Letzorech gufo and mekomo is by kli shemelachto **l'isur**) an example would be to move it so that it should not get ruined (gufo meens to use it)